# How to convert xml file to string without escaping XML using java

Tags: java, xml, file, java-io

I've a `XML` file and want to send its content to caller as string. This is what I'm using:

`return FileUtils.readFileToString(xmlFile);`

but this (or that matter all other ways I tried like reading line by line) escapes XML elements and enclose whole XML with `<string>` like this

`<string>&gt;&amp;lt;.....</string>`

but I want to return
`<a>....</a>`

Comment: There is nothing in `FileUtils.readFileToString()` that would modify the data being read to escape anything.  Either the data already exists that way in the file, or something else is introducing the escapes.  You really haven't provided enough information or shown how you _know_ the data is unescaped in the input file.

Answer (score 1):

I'd advise using a different file reader maybe something like this.

```
private String readFile( String file ) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( new FileReader (file));
    String         line = null;
    StringBuilder  stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    String         ls = System.getProperty("line.separator");

    while( ( line = reader.readLine() ) != null ) {
        stringBuilder.append( line );
        stringBuilder.append( ls );
    }

    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

It's probably a feature of file utils.

Answer (score 0):

According to your question you just want to read the file. You can use `FileReader` and `BufferedReader` to read the file.

```
File f=new File("demo.xml");
        FileReader fr=new FileReader(f);
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(fr);

        String line;
        while((line=br.readLine())!=null)
        {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
```

Hope this answer helps you

Answer (score 0):

IOUtils works well. It's in package org.apache.commons.io. The toString method takes an InputStream as a parameter and returns the contents as a string maintaining format.

```
InputStream is = getClass.getResourceAsStream("foo.xml");
String str = IOUtils.toString(is);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(filename)));

String line;

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

while((line = br.readLine())!= null){

    sb.append(line.trim());
}
```